# Boton buscar con un select option que esta conectado con una funcion php

Tags: php, html

Tengo un problema con el boton buscar. En mi html tengo un asi. En el select 
Me aparecen los datos que tengo en la base de datos 
Pero cuando doy clic en el boton buscar solo me aparece la cédula y el nombre pero en el option no se cambia. Cuando abro la pagina me sale los datos lugar de trabajo quito que es la primera opcion pero cuando yo me registro eligo bogota cuando presiono buscar debe aparecer el nombre de la persona y el lugar de trabajo pero me sale quito la cual es la primera opcion ese dato  no cambia y lo que quiero es que muestre bogota

```
 <?php
include 'base/conexion.php';
include 'base/buscar.php';
include 'base/guardar.php';
$conexion=$conexion;

$query4=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT lt_id, lt_nombre from lugar_trabajo");
if (isset($_POST['lugar_trabajo'])) 
{
$lugar_trabajo=$_POST['lugar_trabajo'];
/*echo $lugar_trabajo;*/
}   
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" placeholder="NOMBRE" value="<?php echo $varnombre?>"> 
<input type="text" id="cedula" name="cedula" placeholder="CEDULA" value="<?php echo $varcedula?>">
<select width="100px" id="lugar_trabajo" name="lugar_trabajo" class="select">
<?php
while ($lugar_trabajo = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)) 
{
?>
<option value="<?php echo $lugar_trabajo['lt_id']?>"> <?php echo $lugar_trabajo['lt_nombre']?> </option>
  <?php
  }
  ?>
 </select>
 <input type="submit" name="boton" value="GUARDAR" onclick="return validar_conductor()">
<input type="submit" name="boton" value="ACTUALIZAR">
<input type="submit" name="boton" value="BUSCAR">
</body>
```

mi funcion para buscar esta

```
<?php
include 'base/conexion.php';
$conexion=$conexion;

$cedula=$_POST["cedula"];
$nombre=$_POST["nombre"];
$lugar_trabajo=$_POST["lugar_trabajo"];


if(isset($_POST["boton"])){
    $VBoton=$_POST["boton"];
    $bus=$_POST["cedula"];

            if($VBoton=="BUSCAR")
            {
                $sql=mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM conductores where 
               cd_cedula='$bus'");
                $res=($sql);
                while ($resul=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){
                    $varnombre=$resul[1];
                    $varcedula=$resul[0];
                    $varlugar_trabajo=$resul[2];
                }
            }   
}
?>
```

Comment: que trae la variable $varlugar_trabajo=$resul[2]; un id, el nombre de la ciudad

Answer (score 0):

te falta hacer un if para agregar el atributo selected al option, segun el lugar de trabajo por tanto el while quedaria asi, una cosa el if lo hice en base al nombre del lugar pero si es el id debes cambiarlo a $lugar_trabajo['lt_id'] en if. un consejo no es necesario usar tanta etiqueta php con una sola se puede hacer.

```
    <?php
     while ($lugar_trabajo = mysqli_fetch_array($query4)) 
     {
       $selected="";
       if(isset($varlugar_trabajo) && $varlugar_trabajo==$lugar_trabajo['lt_nombre']){
        $selected="selected";
       }
       $lt_id=$lugar_trabajo["lt_id"];
       $lt_nombre=$lugar_trabajo["lt_nombre"];
       echo"<option value='".$lt_id."'> ".$lt_nombre." </option>";
 }

 ?>
```